# VBA Getting date from properties of a text file

Tags: vba, properties, text-files

I'm trying to grab the date that a specific text file was uploaded onto the computer.  The date isn't in the actual text file, instead you have to right-click then go to properties to view the date.  I need to read the date into a variable.

I have no idea where to start to try and get this done.

Thank you,

Jesse Smothermon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the built in `FileDateTime()` isnt what your after you can use the FSO:

```
Dim FSO As Object: Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objFile As Object: Set objFile = FSO.Getfile("C:\bleep\bloop.file")

Debug.Print "Date created: " & objFile.DateCreated
Debug.Print "Date last accessed: " & objFile.DateLastAccessed
Debug.Print "Date last modified: " & objFile.DateLastModified
```

If its a date in an extended attribute check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651890/using-vba-to-get-extended-file-attributes) out.

Comment: Do not use `As Object`. That leads to late binding, which sucks. Use a proper reference and `As New Scripting.FileSystemObject` and `As Scripting.File`

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you (I'll accept answer once it lets me)

Comment: @Tomalak: Late binding has its place, though I agree that this isn't it.

Comment: @Roland: Yes it has - in VBScript. ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak: Also when you may have to allow for different versions of, say, Office across your installation domain.