# How to get extended file attribute vba

Tags: shell, vba

Found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651890/using-vba-to-get-extended-file-attributes) which worked, except that I want to set sFile to a specific file.  How would I do that?  (I'm a noob with shell scripts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787870%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (See the parse method)