# get document properties using VBS

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject

I have a folder containing few files.
I would like to get, for each file, a list of all the properties assigned to this file and their values.

I have written these few lines but I am not able to identify the right methods to use in the placeholders MethodIamLookingFor1 (to get list of properties assigned), MethodIamLookingFor2 (to get property name) and MethodIamLookingFor3 (to get property value):

```
Dim sFolder
sFolder = "C:\Batch_DEV\to"
Dim objFSO, objDir, listObjFiles, objFile

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objDir = objFSO.GetFolder(sFolder)
Set listObjFiles = objDir.Files

For Each objFile In listObjFiles
        Wscript.Echo objFile.name & ": "
        listProperties = objFile.MethodIamLookingFor1 
            For Each objFileProperty In listProperties
                Wscript.Echo "property name is: " & objFileProperty.MethodIamLookingFor2
                Wscript.Echo "property value is: " & objFileProperty.MethodIamLookingFor3
            Next
    Next
```

Could you please help?
thanks!

Comment: Look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651890/using-vba-to-get-extended-file-attributes

Comment: @Sorceri You know the difference between VBA and VBScript right?

Comment: @Lankymart You do realize that it can easily be converted to work in VBScript...right?.....

Comment: @Sorceri No really, you'd think I would know that with over 70+ answers in VBScript. Geez. The point is why direct someone to a Excel VBA question who might not know the difference and try to use the code outright?

Answer (score 2):

Code from [Using VBA to get extended file attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651890/using-vba-to-get-extended-file-attributes)

ignore the VBA keyword as it can be converted to VBScript with little effort. See below.

```
Dim fso
Dim txtStream
Dim sFile
Dim oShell

Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oDir
Set oDir = oShell.Namespace(pathToFolder)
Set txtStream = fso.OpenTextFile(pathToTextFile, 2, True, -2)

For Each sFile In oDir.Items
    For i = 0 To 40
       txtStream.WriteLine i & " : " & oDir.GetDetailsOf(oDir.Items, i) & " : " & oDir.GetDetailsOf(sFile, i)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort to explain the link.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall VBScript as having a property that can be used to enumerate file properties. VB6 contained the FileInfo object that would have allowed for that.

Using VBScript you will need to specify each property you want. The files properties are listed on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ft05taf(v=vs.84).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

thanks, I have used the GetDetailsOf instruction you indicated and adapted my code to use https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176615.aspx inputs

```
Dim sFolder
sFolder = "C:\Batch_DEV\to"

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objDir = objShell.Namespace(sFolder)

For Each strFileName in objDir.Items
    Wscript.Echo objDir.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, 0) & ":"
    For i = 0 To 10
        Wscript.Echo  vbtab & "property name is: " & objDir.GetDetailsOf(objDir.Items, i)
        Wscript.Echo  vbtab & "property value is: " & objDir.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, i)
    Next
Next
```

so at the end the methods are:

- MethodIamLookingFor1 ==> GetDetailsOf(objDir.Items, i)
- MethodIamLookingFor2 ==> GetDetailsOf(objDir.Items, i)
- MethodIamLookingFor3 ==> GetDetailsOf(strFileName, i)

I have added a vbtab to enhane the output and here is the result:

> ```
> test.txt:
>          property name is: Nome
>          property value is: test.txt
>          property name is: Dimensione
>          property value is: 351 byte
>          property name is: Tipo elemento
>          property value is: File TXT
>          property name is: Ultima modifica
>          property value is: 23/12/2015 14:34
>          property name is: Data creazione
>          property value is: 29/12/2015 09:30
>          property name is: Data ultimo accesso
>          property value is: 29/12/2015 09:30 word 
> sample.docx:
>          property name is: Nome
>          property value is: word sample.docx
>          property name is: Dimensione
>          property value is: 11,1 KB
>          property name is: Tipo elemento
>          property value is: Documento di Microsoft Word
>          property name is: Ultima modifica
>          property value is: 10/12/2015 16:24
>          property name is: Data creazione
>          property value is: 29/12/2015 09:31
>          property name is: Data ultimo accesso
>          property value is: 29/12/2015 09:31
> ```

Many thanks for the support!

Comment: The deceleration of array in line "Dim listProperties(10)" do nothing in your script . And for next loop  not any benefit in the script result. remove this 4 lines .