# VBA get a list of files in folder and their tags (Keywords)

Tags: vba, tags, metadata, keyword

I am trying to make a macros with a userform in which I'd enter a folder location and make a list of all the files in that directory and also have file tags too, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the tags. What I have so far is:

```
'Disable screen update
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Declare variables
Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long



Range("A2:E2" & LastRow).ClearContents

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(FolderLocation_TextBox.Value)

i = 1

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = oFile.Name
    i = i + 1
Next oFile

'Enable screen update
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

And it get's the list alright. I tried to do

```
Cells(i + 1, 1) = oFile.Tags
```

And that didn't work. Also I found that it's something to do with a code:

```
oFile.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Keywords").Value
```

And it says that it doesn't support this property or method.
Overall I am trying to get a list of all the files and their tags and later I will be trying to make it edit said files tags from excel.

Could someone, please, help me figure this one out? Seems a bit too complex for such a simple thing as metadata extraction.

EDIT:

Found something that could help solve this and edited my code:

```
'Declare variables
Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim oShell As Object

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(FolderLocation_TextBox.Value)

i = 1

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = oFile.Name
    On Error Resume Next
    Cells(i, 2) = oFile.GetDetailsOf(oFile, 18)
    i = i + 1
Next oFile
```

But it also doesn't seem to import any tags

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/file-object#properties) are the full list of properties you can access on a File Object using VBA's FileSystemObject. There's nothing like `.Tags` but you might be interested in `.Attributes`

Comment: From what I get that attribute is a write protection? I am looking for a metadata of a file called tags

Comment: Can you link to something that tells us what a "tag" is, and/or give examples? File attributes are essentially flags that mark a file as "read-only", or "hidden", or "system", or a combination of those. Tell us what information/metadata you're trying to get out of "tags", rather than asking us where the tags are.

Comment: Ah, absolutelly! According to:
https://zapier.com/blog/how-to-use-tags-and-labels/#intro
Tags are keywords you assign to files. Think of them like characteristics for a person: Just like you’d describe someone as "tall," "funny," "brunette," and so on, you’d tag a file "important," "tax info," "just for fun," or "work."

Comment: In windows explorer you get all default properties like: extension, file size, file name, date created, date modified, but one can also add more columns to windows explorer and one of them is "Tags" that you can type in for each file for search convenience. What I am trying to do is to fill this property via excel with the help of VBA. But for starters I need to get a list that actually contains this property :)

Comment: My most recent research found that it possibly ahs to do with .BuiltinDocumentProperties("Keywords").Value but I couldn't get the tags of those files in the directory, I only could say thisworkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Keywords").Value that returned "Sheet1" and it's not an actual tag of the workbook since it has this property blank

Comment: https://www.maketecheasier.com/assets/uploads/2018/03/tag-files-in-windows-add-tags-in-details-pane.png

Comment: Your code will not multi-task, so Excel will be unresponsive whilst this operation takes place.  Better to shell a command line, do a `Dir *.* /s > %temp\myDir.txt` and then parse the text file at `%temp\myDir.txt`.

Comment: @Eduards, I found this answer in SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989708/vba-make-explorer-exe-remove-file-properties, tested it and got the tags. Perhaps, this is what you search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume we have the folder with some files:

[image]

Then we can indeed get the "Tags" from the file by using `.GetDetailsOf` and retrieving the file as an item object we can get the attributes from the file.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetFileAttributes()
'Based on the code from: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=405

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim objShell, objFolder, objFolderItem As Object
Dim FSO, oFolder, oFile As Object
 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
FolderPath = "G:\Till\0262529629\" 'Set folderpath

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Set sheet name

ws.Range("A1:K1").Value = Array("Path", "File Name", "Date Accessed", "Date Modified", "Date Created", "Item Type", "Size", "Availability", "Perceived type", "Comments", "Tags")

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = FSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)

i = 2 'First row to print result

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
On Error Resume Next 'If any attribute is not retrievable ignore and continue
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(oFolder.Path)
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(oFile.Name)
    
    ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = oFolder.Path                             'Folder Path
    ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 0)
    ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 5)
    ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 3)
    ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 4)
    ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 2)
    ws.Cells(i, 7).Value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 1) 'Size
    ws.Cells(i, 8).Value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 8)
    ws.Cells(i, 9).Value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 9)
    ws.Cells(i, 10).Value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 24)
    ws.Cells(i, 11).Value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 18) 'Tags
    i = i + 1
On Error Resume Next
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**End Result:**
[image]

---

The following file attributes can be retrieved (credits to isladogs):

```
.GetDetailsOf(Fileobject item, attribute nr)
```

[Source](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/obtaining-extended-file-properties-attributes-using-vba.294548/)

```
Full list of file attributes available from GetDetailsOf function
=================================================================
NOTE: attributes returning a value will depend on file type

0 - Name
1 - Size
2 - Item type
3 - Date modified
4 - Date created
5 - Date accessed
6 - Attributes
7 - Offline status
8 - Availability
9 - Perceived type
10 - Owner
11 - Kind
12 - Date taken
13 - Contributing artists
14 - Album
15 - Year
16 - Genre
17 - Conductors
18 - Tags
19 - Rating
20 - Authors
21 - Title
22 - Subject
23 - Categories
24 - Comments
25 - Copyright
26 - #
27 - Length
28 - Bit rate
29 - Protected
30 - Camera model
31 - Dimensions
32 - Camera maker
33 - Company
34 - File description
35 - Program name
36 - Duration
37 - Is online
38 - Is recurring
39 - Location
40 - Optional attendee addresses
41 - Optional attendees
42 - Organiser address
43 - Organiser name
44 - Reminder time
45 - Required attendee addresses
46 - Required attendees
47 - Resources
48 - Meeting status
49 - Free/busy status
50 - Total size
51 - Account name
52 - 
53 - Task status
54 - Computer
55 - Anniversary
56 - Assistant's name
57 - Assistant's phone
58 - Birthday
59 - Business address
60 - Business city
61 - Business country/region
62 - Business P.O. box
63 - Business postcode
64 - Business county/region
65 - Business street
66 - Business fax
67 - Business home page
68 - Business phone
69 - Call-back number
70 - Car phone
71 - Children
72 - Company main phone
73 - Department
74 - Email address
75 - Email2
76 - Email3
77 - Email list
78 - Email display name
79 - File as
80 - First name
81 - Full name
82 - Gender
83 - Given name
84 - Hobbies
85 - Home address
86 - Home city
87 - Home country/region
88 - Home P.O. box
89 - Home postcode
90 - Home county/region
91 - Home street
92 - Home fax
93 - Home phone
94 - IM addresses
95 - Initials
96 - Job title
97 - Label
98 - Surname
99 - Postal address
100 - Middle name
101 - Mobile phone
102 - Nickname
103 - Office location
104 - Other address
105 - Other city
106 - Other country/region
107 - Other P.O. box
108 - Other postcode
109 - Other county/region
110 - Other street
111 - Pager
112 - Personal title
113 - City
114 - Country/region
115 - P.O. box
116 - Postcode
117 - County/Region
118 - Street
119 - Primary email
120 - Primary phone
121 - Profession
122 - Spouse/Partner
123 - Suffix
124 - TTY/TTD phone
125 - Telex
126 - Web page
127 - Content status
128 - Content type
129 - Date acquired
130 - Date archived
131 - Date completed
132 - Device category
133 - Connected
134 - Discovery method
135 - Friendly name
136 - Local computer
137 - Manufacturer
138 - Model
139 - Paired
140 - Classification
141 - Status
142 - Status
143 - Client ID
144 - Contributors
145 - Content created
146 - Last printed
147 - Date last saved
148 - Division
149 - Document ID
150 - Pages
151 - Slides
152 - Total editing time
153 - Word count
154 - Due date
155 - End date
156 - File count
157 - File extension
158 - Filename
159 - File version
160 - Flag colour
161 - Flag status
162 - Space free
163 - 
164 - 
165 - Group
166 - Sharing type
167 - Bit depth
168 - Horizontal resolution
169 - Width
170 - Vertical resolution
171 - Height
172 - Importance
173 - Is attachment
174 - Is deleted
175 - Encryption status
176 - Has flag
177 - Is completed
178 - Incomplete
179 - Read status
180 - Shared
181 - Creators
182 - Date
183 - Folder name
184 - Folder path
185 - Folder
186 - Participants
187 - Path
188 - By location
189 - Type
190 - Contact names
191 - Entry type
192 - Language
193 - Date visited
194 - Description
195 - Link status
196 - Link target
197 - URL
198 - 
199 - 
200 - 
201 - Media created
202 - Date released
203 - Encoded by
204 - Episode number
205 - Producers
206 - Publisher
207 - Season number
208 - Subtitle
209 - User web URL
210 - Writers
211 - 
212 - Attachments
213 - Bcc addresses
214 - Bcc
215 - Cc addresses
216 - Cc
217 - Conversation ID
218 - Date received
219 - Date sent
220 - From addresses
221 - From
222 - Has attachments
223 - Sender address
224 - Sender name
225 - Store
226 - To addresses
227 - To do title
228 - To
229 - Mileage
230 - Album artist
231 - Sort album artist
232 - Album ID
233 - Sort album
234 - Sort contributing artists
235 - Beats-per-minute
236 - Composers
237 - Sort composer
238 - Disc
239 - Initial key
240 - Part of a compilation
241 - Mood
242 - Part of set
243 - Full stop
244 - Colour
245 - Parental rating
246 - Parental rating reason
247 - Space used
248 - EXIF version
249 - Event
250 - Exposure bias
251 - Exposure program
252 - Exposure time
253 - F-stop
254 - Flash mode
255 - Focal length
256 - 35mm focal length
257 - ISO speed
258 - Lens maker
259 - Lens model
260 - Light source
261 - Max aperture
262 - Metering mode
263 - Orientation
264 - People
265 - Program mode
266 - Saturation
267 - Subject distance
268 - White balance
269 - Priority
270 - Project
271 - Channel number
272 - Episode name
273 - Closed captioning
274 - Rerun
275 - SAP
276 - Broadcast date
277 - Program description
278 - Recording time
279 - Station call sign
280 - Station name
281 - Summary
282 - Snippets
283 - Auto summary
284 - Relevance
285 - File ownership
286 - Sensitivity
287 - Shared with
287 - Shared with: Homegroup
288 - Sharing status
288 - Sharing status: Shared
289 - 
289 - : Available
290 - Product name
291 - Product version
292 - Support link
293 - Source
294 - Start date
295 - Sharing
296 - Sync status
297 - Billing information
298 - Complete
299 - Task owner
300 - Sort title
301 - Total file size
302 - Legal trademarks
303 - Video compression
304 - Directors
305 - Data rate
306 - Frame height
307 - Frame rate
308 - Frame width
309 - Video orientation
310 - Total bitrate
311 - 
312 - 
313 - 
314 - 
315 - 
316 - 
317 - 
318 - 
319 - 
320 -
```

---

**Update**
If you would like to loop through all the file attributes for a file you can add this piece of code. It will give you all the attributes for each file and then you could filter out a specific attribute and look how many times it occurs :)

Code is inserted after `i = i + 1` part in above code.

```
   'i = i + 1
    
    
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row 'Last row for the attribute column.
    
    For j = 0 To 320 'Loop through all the possible attributes
        ws.Cells(lrow + 1, 14).Value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(Null, j) 'File Attribute 
        ws.Cells(lrow + 1, 15).Value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, j) 'File Attribute Value
        lrow = lrow + 1
    Next j
    
'On Error Resume Next
```

Example of output:

[image]

Comment: Glad it helped you :), just let me know if you have any further questions and I will try my best answer you. Happy coding =)!!

Comment: Actually I do... there's options regarding the file description under numbers 34, 277 and 134 or so, but none of them actually get the description from the file. You see in windows explorer I get two options for the description (Both called description) of which one is always empty but the other will most often be filled. That description data comes from Solidworks file properties. I wonder if there's a way to pinpoint the number for that attribute without trial and error about 300 times :D

Comment: Ohhh, that's a very good question! I haven't worked with Solidworks :(. I also noticed that the file attributes varies even for the same file type, which make it difficult to pinpoint which attributes that are relevant/usually populated. // Maybe not the best solution; I would take all the files I'm interested in, and then loop through those files. Get some statistics about which attributes that are generally populated and then only include those attributes in the final code... To help you, I updated the code with looping through the attributes so you don't need to do it manually :)

Comment: I ran it and turns out none of the attributes is the one I'm looking for. I know for a fact that Solid works file properties are stored as extended attributes much like tags, comments, etc. I've seen a macro that let's you edit those from excel:
https://www.codestack.net/solidworks-document-manager-api/document/data-storage/custom-properties/excel-functions/
So one of those properties will always be a description that is also available in windows explorer to see along with the rest of extended attributes

Comment: So Sad :(. Really interesting. You're totally right that it have extra attributes i.e. kind of custom properties. I've tried a bit but don't have the program neither experience with any of these files. It seems that you should be able to read the file and get the properties by using `.GetCustomProperty(FieldName, type)`, however it seems that you need to have the application installed. I also tried this [source](https://help.solidworks.com/2017/English/api/swdocmgrapi/SOLIDWORKS.Interop.swdocumentmgr~SOLIDWORKS.Interop.swdocumentmgr.ISwDMDocument~GetCustomProperty.html) but no success.

Comment: Just for [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297739/modify-excel-vba-function-for-file-properties)