# How to get company name of user using word vba?

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I know how to get author name and user name of word application. But I don't know how to get detail of Company property.

Can anybody suggest me how can I get name of company set by use in Word using VBA?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651890/using-vba-to-get-extended-file-attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the Company property that appears here:

[image]

You can use `ThisDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Company")`

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you