# Extended file attributes from a .PDF (file) using VBA in excel

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I'm trying to understand what goes wrong with the below...
Bassicaly I List a series of files in an excel sheet and I'm also looking to add the tags for each file.
This is not a problem for office file as I'm using the ".BuiltinDocumentProperties("Keywords").Value".

However when it comes to Pdf files 
I thought that it would be straight forward to use the ".GetDetailsof()"       in order to get access to the extended properties.

Well... for some reason I get the below,

```
sValue = oDir.GetDetailsOf(oDir.Items, 18)

'Returns the "Date Modified"
```

While when I use the

```
sValue = objFile.DateLastModified
'Returns the actual Value e.g. 09/11/2012 07:01:48
```

Any comments or suggestions will be much appreciated.

P.S.1 I have already read the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651890/using-vba-to-get-extended-file-attributes) related to extended file attributes.
I hope that I din't miss anything.

P.S.2 To be able to add values to a pdf file I use the [File Meta Data](https://filemeta.codeplex.com)

Comment: Isn't "Date Modified" 3 not 18 ?

Comment: If you want the value for a specific file then you need `sValue = oDir.GetDetailsOf(objFile, 18)`

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the quick response! 
On your first comment you are right "Date modified" is 3 not 18, 18 is the "Tags" but all I get is "Tags" and not the value that is under "Tags" Value is "221" 
With regards to the second comment I do have this line already in my code but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code which provides an overview of what properties are available and how to access them.

Adapted from:  http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/157834-VBA-FileSystemObject-Properties-Dimensions-Size-and-Vertical-resolution

```
Sub GetDetails()
  Dim oShell As Object
  Dim oFile As Object
  Dim oFldr As Object
  Dim lRow As Long
  Dim iCol As Integer
  Dim vArray As Variant
  vArray = Array(0, 1, 3, 4, 18)


  Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  lRow = 1
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select the Folder..."
    If .Show Then
      Set oFldr = oShell.Namespace(.SelectedItems(1))
      With oFldr
        For iCol = 0 To 286
          Cells(lRow, iCol + 1) = .getdetailsof(.items, iCol)
        Next iCol
        For Each oFile In .items
          lRow = lRow + 1
          For iCol = 0 To 286
            Cells(lRow, iCol + 1) = .getdetailsof(oFile, iCol)
          Next iCol
        Next oFile
      End With
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code very convenient to check basically that the the 3 "word" files that I have under the selected folder give me all the properties as expected apart from the 1 pdf file that although I have a "Tag" and "Author " value on it the cell returns blank.

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem occurs due to the fact that the properties on the pdf are given after installing the "File Meta data" (I have a link above)
through the Rclick on the pdf file> Properties> Details> Tags