# Excel VBA workbook property for last modified vs SaveDate

Tags: vba, excel

I am noticing users modifying excel workbooks but the date for the SaveDate is not being updated. We would like to know when the last updated their workbooks.

As far as I can tell the 
[`Workbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/8hx26fff(v=vs.120)) collection does not include a property for ModifiedDate. Is there some way we can tell our users to save so that the SaveDate is updated?

Or can we actually get the Modified date from VBA?

Comment: I would guess you could just retrieve that information using the FileDateTime function.

Comment: I normally use `Scripting.FileSystemObject` to get the file's `.DateLastModified`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datelastmodified-property

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 do you want to write this as an answer? I can then accept it since yes, this does solve the problem! And thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that there is a native function to get a file's `Date Modified` date, but you can pretty easily use the windows scripting reference to [`FileSystemObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/hww8txat(v=vs.84)) to get the [`File.DateLastModified`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datelastmodified-property) property.

I'm not completely sure how you'd like to implement this, but here are two examples you could consider:

When the following example is triggered, it reaches the code to prompt the user if the `ActiveWorkbook` has unsaved changes and if the last save was longer than 15 minutes ago.

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

If DateDiff("n", fso.getfile(wb.FullName).DateLastModified, Now) > 15 And wb.Saved = False Then
    'prompt user to save or save for them
End If
```

If there are potentially multiple workbooks open then you might want to use the next example which loops through all open workbooks before completing the same operation as above.

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim wb As Workbook
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks

    Dim wbFile As Object
    Set wbFile = fso.getfile(wb.FullName)

    Debug.Print "filename:  " & wbFile.name & vbCrLf & _
                "modified:  " & wbFile.DateLastModified & vbCrLf

    If DateDiff("n", wbFile.DateLastModified, Now) > 15 And wb.Saved = False Then
        'prompt user to save or save for them
    End If

Next wb
```

If for some reason you instead have to loop through a directory to look for files, [this site gives a nice example](http://www.xl-central.com/list-files-fso.html) on how to do so.

Comment: For anyone browsing here in the future, you can also reference this answer for another approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651890/using-vba-to-get-extended-file-attributes