# How to check the properties of an attached excel file in outlook?

Tags: excel, vba, properties, outlook

I need your help. 
Can not find way to do this.
I got an Outlook emails with lots of attachments (excel files). I want to automatically check the properties of the attached excel file(Excel file properties:By title, by subject, by tags, by categories and etc). So can anyone tell me what code do i need to write in VBA for solving my problem.?

Comment: you can save/open all attachments and then use this code to check document properties https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651890/using-vba-to-get-extended-file-attributes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to check properties of attachments in Outlook, but you can certainly download all attachments, and check the properties of these files after they have been downloaded.

Arg 1 = Folder name of folder inside your Inbox
Arg 2 = File extension, "" is every file
Arg 3 = Save folder, "C:\Users\Ron\test" or ""
              If you use "" it will create a date/time stamped folder for you in your "Documents" folder
              Note: If you use this "C:\Users\Ron\test" the folder must exist.

This will copy all files from “MyFolder” to a new folder in the Documents folder

```
SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder "MyFolder", "", ""
```

Download attachments:

```
Sub SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder(OutlookFolderInInbox As String, _
                                 ExtString As String, DestFolder As String)
    Dim ns As Namespace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim MyDocPath As String
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim wsh As Object
    Dim fs As Object

    On Error GoTo ThisMacro_err

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(OutlookFolderInInbox)

    I = 0
    ' Check subfolder for messages and exit of none found
    If SubFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in this folder : " & OutlookFolderInInbox, _
               vbInformation, "Nothing Found"
        Set SubFolder = Nothing
        Set Inbox = Nothing
        Set ns = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Create DestFolder if DestFolder = ""
    If DestFolder = "" Then
        Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        MyDocPath = wsh.SpecialFolders.Item("mydocuments")
        DestFolder = MyDocPath & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh-mm-ss")
        If Not fs.FolderExists(DestFolder) Then
            fs.CreateFolder DestFolder
        End If
    End If

    If Right(DestFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        DestFolder = DestFolder & "\"
    End If

    ' Check each message for attachments and extensions
    For Each Item In SubFolder.Items
        For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
            If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then
                FileName = DestFolder & Item.SenderName & " " & Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                I = I + 1
            End If
        Next Atmt
    Next Item

    ' Show this message when Finished
    If I > 0 Then
        MsgBox "You can find the files here : " _
             & DestFolder, vbInformation, "Finished!"
    Else
        MsgBox "No attached files in your mail.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
    End If

    ' Clear memory
ThisMacro_exit:
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing
    Set wsh = Nothing
    Exit Sub

    ' Error information
ThisMacro_err:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
         & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
         & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder" _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
         , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume ThisMacro_exit

End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/saveatt.htm

Next, and last, list all files in a folder, and find the relevant properties of each.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ListFilesInFolder(ByVal SourceFolderName As String, ByVal IncludeSubfolders As Boolean)

'Declaring variables
Dim FSO As Object
Dim SourceFolder As Object
Dim SubFolder As Object
Dim FileItem As Object
Dim r As Long

'Creating object of FileSystemObject
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

r = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1

For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files

    'Display file properties
     Cells(r, 1).Formula = FileItem.Name
     Cells(r, 2).Formula = FileItem.Path
     Cells(r, 3).Formula = FileItem.Size
     Cells(r, 4).Formula = FileItem.DateCreated
     Cells(r, 5).Formula = FileItem.DateLastModified

     r = r + 1

Next FileItem

'Getting files in sub folders
If IncludeSubfolders Then
     For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.SubFolders
        'Calling same procedure for sub folders
        ListFilesInFolder SubFolder.Path, True
     Next SubFolder
End If

Set FileItem = Nothing
Set SourceFolder = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing

ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True

End Sub


Sub TestListFilesInFolder()

'Declaring variable
Dim FolderPath As String

'Disabling screen updates
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Getting the folder path from text box
FolderPath = Sheet1.TextBox1.Value

ActiveSheet.Activate

'Clearing the content from columns A:E
Columns("A:E").Select
Selection.ClearContents


'Adding headers
Range("A14").Formula = "File Name:"
Range("B14").Formula = "Path:"
Range("C14").Formula = "File Size:"
Range("D14").Formula = "Date Created:"
Range("E14").Formula = "Date Last Modified:"

'Formating of the headers
Range("A14:E14").Font.Bold = True

'Calling ListFilesInFolder macro
ListFilesInFolder FolderPath, True

'Auto adjusting the size of the columns
Columns("A:E").Select
Selection.Columns.AutoFit

Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```