# Replace string with string variable - Error 91

Tags: excel, vba, string, namespaces

***Background***

Recently I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57723867/9758194) which involved looking at a file's properties. Eventually the code I put up worked fine, but there is one thing about it that got me puzzled.

***Problem***

There are two specific lines where I wanted to replace a (to me what looks like) a string, with a variable, more specifically, try the following:

```
Sub TestForSO()

Dim oDir As Object: Set oDir = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace("C:\Users\...\")
Debug.Print oDir.GetDetailsOf(oDir.Items, 1)

End Sub
```

Replace the pathname to a directory which includes an excel file, and it should return the property value just fine.

Now when I try to replace the full path with a variable the following throws an "Runtime Error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set" on the debug.print line:

```
Sub TestForSO()

Dim MainPath As String: MainPath = "C:\Users\...\"
Dim oDir As Object: Set oDir = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(MainPath)
Debug.Print oDir.GetDetailsOf(oDir.Items, 1)

End Sub
```

***Solution***

A bit peculiar to me that the following did work:

```
Sub TestForSO()

Dim MainPath As String: MainPath = "C:\Users\...\"
Dim oDir As Object: Set oDir = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(CStr(MainPath))
Debug.Print oDir.GetDetailsOf(oDir.Items, 1)

End Sub
```

I do not understand the difference per se as the code below will give the same result through "Watches":

```
Sub test()

Dim check1 As String, check2 As String

check1 = "Hello"
check2 = CStr("Hello")

End Sub
```

[image]

***Question***

Does somebody understand why the string variable on itself was not enough and would throw an error? Why would adding `Cstr()` make the code work when seemingly it's the same data type?

Comment: Can you declare `MainPath` as a `Variant` and remove the `CStr` and see if it works? When I was answering the same question I ran into issues when I declared my path as a `String` as `NameSpace` expects a `Variant`. But the fact that it accepts it using `CStr` has got me baffled.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but function `Cstr` returns a variant of subtype string (http://www.csidata.com/custserv/onlinehelp/vbsdocs/vbs89.htm). If you define `Mainpath` as Variant, it will work. And it works with `Cstr` because it returns actually a Variant.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns That would explain it

Comment: I don't think @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns is correct. He linked to the **VBScript** help for `CStr()`. In VBScript, everything is a `Variant`. **VBA** however is a typed language and looking at the help for [VBA CStr](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions), it states that it returns the data type `String`. Declaring it as `Variant` works, because that's what [Namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-namespace) expects. Also: VBA does some weird conversions behind the scenes when passing parameters.

Comment: That's why I said just a shot in the dark. The clue in the link provided by @HelO'Ween is the line *This technique is consistent with the conversion of all other intrinsic types to their equivalent Variant subtypes* So reading that I understand that all conversions returns a Variant with a subtype. And because `Namespace` expects a Variant, it works. Anyways, I did not found anything official and clear, sorry about that, but I think it's clearer what I say, even if it's a clumsy theory, that *VBA does some weird conversions*

Comment: It's funny if I reference shell32.dll and change `Object` to `Shell` it works. Maybe it depends somehow on early/late binding?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, your theory seems supported through VBA. If I do not declare check2, the watch on check2 will return `Variant\String` on this line: `check2 = Cstr(check1)`, even when check1 has a confirmed string type value. Declaring MainPath as variant in that case does the job (or keeping `Cstr()`). Seems like you could post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation about **[Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-namespace)**, it needs a parameter that must be a Variant or can be a string that specifies the path of the folder.

That explains why these 2 methods work with no problems:

```
Set oDir = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace("C:\Users\...\ 'string path
```

Or defining a Variant variable:

```
Dim MainPath As Variant: MainPath = "C:\Users\...\"
Dim oDir As Object: Set oDir = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(CStr(MainPath))
```

But defining `MainPath` as string causes error *Runtime Error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set*

OP found a solution. If `MainPath` declared as string, and combined with **[Cstr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions)**, the code works.

It's just a theory, but some unnoficial sources (**not directly related to VBA**) mention that `Cstr` converts the value to a variant with a subtype.

http://www.csidata.com/custserv/onlinehelp/vbsdocs/vbs89.htm
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/HFMAD/ch10s06s04s03.html

Actually, the **[official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions)** it's kind of confusing, because at first lines it says:

> *Each function coerces an expression to a specific data type.*

and later on it says

> *The function name determines the return type*

But if we read carefully, there is also some important information like this:

> "...*In general, you can document your code using the data-type
>   conversion functions to show that **the result of some operation
>   should be expressed as a particular data type** rather than the
>   default data type*..."

And also:

> "...*This technique is consistent with the conversion of all other
>   intrinsic types **to their equivalent Variant subtypes***..."

So after doing some research and thinking about it in the last 24 hours, and reading a lot of times the previous paragraphs I've posted, I would dare to say that all conversion functions returns a Variant with a subtype. In this case, `CStr` does return a Variant that is *being coerced to be expressed as string* being string the subtype, but the data is Variant.

That would explain why doing `Cstr(MainPath)` makes the code works.

Comment: Thanks for the post. As per my last comment I've checked `check2 = Cstr(check1)` through watches and indeed a `variant/string` is returned unless you declare `check2` other than variant (or not at all).