# Fetching file properties with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to implement a version control to my .xlsm files via version number written in the Summary --> Keywords field of .xlsm file properties.
Is there a way to fetch this data and copy it to a worksheet using VBA?
[image]

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651890/using-vba-to-get-extended-file-attributes). That should help you on your way

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties` collection.

```vb
Dim propKeywords As DocumentProperty
Set propKeywords = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Keywords")

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = propKeywords.Value
```

You can also easily set these properties via VBA, e.g. for your use-case, setting the version to 2.0:

```vb
propKeywords.Value = "2.0"
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @VBA_trainee, just FYI: surprisingly, saying thank you is actually discouraged on StackOverflow ‍♂️, please take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)